# text input wont become variable javascript

Tags: javascript, variables

document.result.word.value works fine if it isn't a variable but as soon as i make it one it gives errors like "inputWord.charAt is not a function"

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#submit").click(function() {
    var amountOfLetters = 0;
    var inputWord = document.result.word.value.toLowerCase;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++) {
        var letter = inputWord.charAt(i);
        var counter = compWord.indexOf(letter);
        if(counter > -1) {
            amountOfLetters++;
        }
    }
    var isValidWord = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < 8939; i++) {
        if(inputWord == library[i]) {
            isValidWord = 1;
            break;
        };
    };
    if(isValidWord == 0) {
        alert("You cannot use that word");
        $('#getWord').val('');
    } else {
        $(".left").append("<p id='list'>" + inputWord + "(" + amountOfLetters + ")" + "</p>");
        var compChoice = library[Math.floor((Math.random() * 8938) + 1)];
        $(".right").append("<p id='list'>" + compChoice + "</p>");
        $('#getWord').val('');
    };
});
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`toLowerCase` is [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase), try to call it like this:

```
 var inputWord = document.result.word.value.toLowerCase();
```

Comment: To be more specific, your original code was assigning to the `inputWord` variable a reference to the actual `toLowerCase` function that's built into every String object. Now you're trying to call the `charAt()` method on a function, not on a string - thus the error message you received.